# is it possible to order by column based on value-group, in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

suppose this is my table

```
name    status
ab      1
cd      4
ef      -2
mn      3
pq      -1
xy      2
```

defination of status:

```
1,2     = success
3,4     = failure
-1,-2   = error
```

expected results after order by
(order by status based on success, failure, error)

```
ab      1
xy      2
cd      4
mn      3
ef      -2
pq      -1
```

while simple order by status gives this

```
ab      1
xy      2
mn      3
cd      4
pq      -1
ef      -2
```

Is there a way to sort in expected way, without adding a column that maps similar status to a certain value?

Comment: How does the database know what integers are in the same status?

Comment: How do you want to order two rows that have status 1 and 2, both success, but different status, 1 < 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement:

```
order by (case when status in (1, 2) then 1
               when status in (3, 4) then 2
               else 3
          end)
```

If you have a reference table, then you can join to that to get the information as well.